# Limitar a quantidade de resultados que aparecem no autocomplete do jquery-iu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input, autocompletar

Estou usando o *jquery-iu Autocomplete* e está tudo funcionando perfeitamente. Porém gostaria de melhorar o script em um ponto. Eu gostaria de limitar os resultados. Porque se eu digitar *A* no input, aparece INÚMEROS resultados e isso é ruim do ponto de vista estético. Ao menos ao meu ver. Eu gostaria de quando eu digitasse *A* aparecesse uns 5 resultados.

Aqui está tudo que estou falando: http://jsfiddle.net/hr64a7r8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prescisa somente usar uma função na source em vez de usar a Array. Desse modo filtra o resultado e só a quantidade que quer para a *callback* da função. Ou seja mude:

```
source: availableTags
```

Para:

```
source: function (request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
    response(results.slice(0, 5));
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8cg9a966/

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei em inglês a resposta perfeita para o meu problema, foi só mudar a parte que exibia os resultados

Isso

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [<?php echo $atcat ?>];
            $( "#blog" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

virou isso

```
<script>    
$(function() {
var src = [<?php echo $atcat ?>];

 $("#categoria").autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(src, request.term);

        response(results.slice(0, 5));
    }
});                    
});                
</script>
```